# Recover text from select()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to recover the text from the select function instead of show an alert in a variable. `#article` is the id of my text area.

If you have another technique i will take it.

```
function getText() {
  $('#article').select(function() {
    alert("Hello");
  });
}
```

From comments:

The purpose is to format the selection as BOLD.

This is not possible with a text area, so it's necessary to look into making an editor, possibly using a contentEditable div.

Comment: To be clear with what you're asking, are you trying to get the selected text from within a `textarea` element?

Comment: The objective is to bold the text select by the user. But since yesterday i try differents techniques to do this but none work.

Comment: To bold the text within the textarea? If so, that's not possible.

Comment: If i put tags around the text when i replace it  i can no ?

Comment: No. You can only style the content of a textarea as one. You cannot change portions of it. If you want that behaviour I'd suggest using one of the many WYSIWYG editors already available.

Comment: You can use a `contentEditable` div.

Comment: I dont think to this. My (beginner) bad. Yeah i think the idea of @chrisz is the good one. I want to have an editor for someone who doesn't know html.

Comment: I will work on this idea of contentEditable div. Thanks guys ! <3

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan have suggested, use a WYSIWYG editor. There is no need to re-invent the wheel. There are a couple of them out there, one example is [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/).

Comment: I add ckeditor to my project. It's perfect !

Answer (score 0):

If you're inside the select function try

```
this.value
```

Comment: I am using a text area. The project is to do a text editor to create news

Answer (score 0):

With the idea of @RoryMcCrossan and @chrisz i use an WYSIWYG editor (ckeditor for my part). It works pretty good and it's really easy to install.

Comment: It should be a comment instead of posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value of the select field using val().

```
function getText() {
  $('#article').select(function() {
    var selectedText = $(this).val();
  });
}
```

selectedText will be your value i.e option which they selected